# how to stop redirecting to controller page when submitting form data via ajax post in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to submit form data from view to controller using Ajax post and return success message.And ajax in my view send data to function in controller successfully but controller function does not return response back to ajax success function.

my Controller - profile.php

```
function save()
 {
      $response = array();
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Title cant be empty ', 'required');
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
             $param = $this->input->post();
             unset($param['submit']);
             $param['rid']=$this->session->userdata('id');  

            $profile_id = $param['profile_id'];
            unset($param['profile_id']);
            if($profile_id == 0)
            {

             $inserts = $this->profile_model->insert($param);
             if( $inserts>0){
                 $response['status'] = TRUE;
                 $response['notif'] ="success add profile details";
             }else{
                    $response['status'] = FALSE;
                    $response['notif']  = 'Server wrong, please save again';
            }
            }else{

            }

     }else{
            $response['status'] = FALSE;
            $response['notif']  = validation_errors();
     }
 echo json_encode($response);

 }
```

view - profile_new_user.php

```
             ?>
    <form method="POST" id="form_profile" action="<?php echo base_url().'profile/save'; ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="0"><!-------event id---------->
     <div class="form-group">

                        <label>Prefix</label>
                         <select name="prefix" class="form-control">
.
.
.
                     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
     </div>
    </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#form_profile").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: $(this).attr("action"),
  dataType :'JSON',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function(data)
   { 

   if(data.status){   
       alert('ok');
   }else{
        alert('not ok');
   }
   }
})
});
   });
```

model - profile_model.php

```
function insert($data)
 {
  $this->db->insert('user_profile', $data);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
 }
```

after I click submit button page redirect to url - http://localhost/ptm6/profile/save and page shows

{"status":true,"notif":"success add profile details"}

in plain text.

I expect to show alert message without any redirection.

Comment: What you are getting in data ?

Comment: data: $(this).serialize(), -  this send serialized form data to controller.

Comment: I mean inside the success, try to alert(data) or alert(data.status)

Comment: i already tried,it didn't work.

Comment: success: function(data)
   { 
        alert('not ok');
 
   } - even this didn't work

Comment: you have an empty else block, may be its going inside that and not returning anything

Comment: no,it echo {"status":true,"notif":"success add profile details"} as i mentioned.which means it get inside "if($profile_id == 0){ "

Comment: do a `return ['status', 'success']` and check in Ajax if it returned

Comment: no,same error occurred.

Comment: on chrome, in your network tab what is happening? Is your controller returning anything or maybe an error in your controller is preventing the json to be returned, or even in your model is the data being inserted is not correct.

Comment: in network tab it shows,Name= save,status=200,type=document values

Comment: response header -                                                                                   
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2019 18:25:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=92
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: is this means function returns empty object? - "Content-Length: 0"

Comment: you say your controller is named "profile_new_user" but you call controller "profile" ?